# Configuring TFS Extensions for SharePoint on remote server

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013, tfs-2015

We have TFS 2013 on a standalone server and TFS sharepoint extensions on a separate sharepoint 2013 server. we have upgraded TFS 2013 to TFS 2015 update 2 which has caused some components to break when we go to project portal (tfs sharepoint site), throwing `HTTP 500 error`. However when i go to sharepoint server, there is no upgrade path in the installation files from tfs 2013 sharepoint extensions to tfs 2015 sharepoint extension. am i missing something here?

Comment: You need to uninstall the 2013 Sharepoint Extensions and then install the 2015 extensions. There is no upgrade, simply remove and install.

Comment: Did you re-configure SharePoint extension after upgrading?

Comment: no i did not. i couldn't find an option to re-configure. but @jessehouwing reckons i have to uninstall existing and re-install new ones which i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `TFS Administration Console`, select your TFS server name, click `Remove Feature`, and remove `SharePoint feature`. Then select `Extensions for SharePoint Products` to re-configure SharePoint.

[image]

Comment: should i do that on the tfs server or on the sharepoint server where the extensions are installed?

Comment: You need to go to TFS application tier machine. As you are using a standalone server, you would go to TFS server and open TFS Administration Console as attached screenshot.